# Retrieving Value from XML using grep and regular expressions

Tags: regex, unix, grep

I  have the below response being returned from my build system. The build generates multiple artifacts and I want to extract the link to particular artifact from the response below. Let us say something.exe.

```
<Artifacts>
    <artifact name="artifact1" version="1.0" buildId="13321123" make_target="beta" branch="branchName" date="2017-04-21 00:31:38.74856-07" 
            endtime="2017-04-21 00:59:54.680601-07"
            status="succeeded"
            change="e850b01967222464ffca02bf94dc711236fa978a"
            released="no">
        <file url="http://build.system.org/path/to/artifact/folder/MD5SUM.txt"/><file url="http://build.system.org/path/to/artifact/folder/SHA1SUM.txt"/><file url="http://build.system.org/path/to/artifact/folder/SHA256SUM.txt"/><file url="http://build.system.org/path/to/artifact/folder/something.exe"/><file url="http://build.system.org/path/to/artifact/folder/something_x64.msi"/>
    </artifact>
</Artifacts>
```

I would like to know a way to extract just the URL for something.exe. I have tried using piping the curl output and run a grep -E with a regular expression but that gives me the entire line instead.

```
curl -s --request GET http://build.system.org/path/to/artifact/folder/api/?build=13321123 | grep -E 'file url='
curl -s --request GET http://build.system.org/path/to/artifact/folder/api/?build=13321123 | | grep -E 'file url="http\S+OVF10.ova"'
```

Is there a way to just extract the following ?

```
http://build.system.org/path/to/artifact/folder/something.exe
```

Comment: is this going to be the only url ending with .exe?

Comment: yes. there will be only one line ending with .exe

Comment: don't use grep to parse xml, use xml parsers

Answer (score 2):

The righteous way would be to use XML tools in this case, such as [***xmlstarlet***](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/)

But that, of course, requires a valid XML structure. A valid XML structure would look like:

```
<artifact name="artifact1" version="1.0" buildId="13321123" make_target="beta" branch="branchName" date="2017-04-21 00:31:38.74856-07" 
        endtime="2017-04-21 00:59:54.680601-07"
       status="succeeded"
       change="e850b01967222464ffca02bf94dc711236fa978a"
       released="no">
    <file url="http://build.system.org/path/to/artifact/folder/MD5SUM.txt"/><file url="http://build.system.org/path/to/artifact/folder/SHA1SUM.txt"/><file url="http://build.system.org/path/to/artifact/folder/SHA256SUM.txt"/><file url="http://build.system.org/path/to/artifact/folder/something.exe"/><file url="http://build.system.org/path/to/artifact/folder/something_x64.msi"/>
</artifact>
```

The command:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//artifact/file[contains(@url,'something.exe')]/@url" -n xmlfile
```

The output:

```
http://build.system.org/path/to/artifact/folder/something.exe
```

---

`-v` option (or --value-of ) - print value of XPATH expression

The XPATH [***contains()***](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-contains) function returns `true` if the first argument string contains the second argument string, and otherwise returns `false`.

Answer (score 1):

As *RomanPerekhrest* said, use an xml parser for this kind of task. For your example input you could use xmlstarlet like this:

```
xml sel -t -m 'Artifacts/artifact/file [contains(@url, "something.exe")]' -v @url
```

Output:

```
http://build.system.org/path/to/artifact/folder/something.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex should work: `([\w\d\s]*.exe)"\/>` (it searches for a string that consists of `(/somename.exe"/>` , where someonemae must consist of letters, digits, or basic space signs ("_","-"," ").

```
$ regex="([\w\d\s]*.exe)"\/>"
$ echo $input | grep -oP "$regex"
```

Though, as someone mentioned above, you shouldn't use regex to parse xml, use xml parsers.